# Why is GROUP BY on FULLTEXT INDEX using temporary?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm using this table (MySQL / Engine: MyISAM) :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `id_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_doc` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `node_id` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `keywords` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `page_type` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `page_screen_id` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `page_screen_question` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_activity`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(255)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `node_id` (`node_id`,`title`,`name`,`keywords`,`page_type`,`page_screen_id`,`page_screen_question`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

(There are about 100000 rows)

Here is my query:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT 1
FROM `activities`
GROUP BY `node_id`, `title`, `name`, `keywords`, `page_type`, `page_screen_id`, `page_screen_question`;
```

- id: 1
- select_type: SIMPLE
- table: activities
- type: ALL
- possible_keys: NULL
- key: NULL
- key_len: NULL
- ref: NULL
- rows: 613011
- Extra: **Using temporary; Using filesort**

I do not understand why my query uses temporary... and I don't know how to avoid this... Thanks

Comment: [`In some cases, MySQL is able to do much better than that and to avoid creation of temporary tables by using index access.`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Comment: @DavidStarkey I read this topic, but there is actually an index on my `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Is there a reason temporary is an issue?

Comment: @DavidStarkey MySQL manuals says (unless i'm mistaken) that when there is an index, engine does not need temporary

Comment: The index might need to be on the item in the `GROUP BY` which, in your case, there are several fields there and not all are indexed.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Thx but I don't understand (sorry): I have an index on all fields: `FULLTEXT KEY node_id (node_id,title,name,keywords,page_type,page_screen_id,page_screen_question)`

Answer (score 1):

Should rather be a comment, but it's more readable this way:

Please execute this query

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) AS tablename,
   CONCAT(ROUND(table_rows / 1000000, 2), 'M')                                    rows,
   CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                    data,
   CONCAT(ROUND(index_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                   idx,
   CONCAT(ROUND(( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') total_size,
   ROUND(index_length / data_length, 2)                                           idxfrac
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database()
AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

and check if your table or the index actually fits into memory. If it doesn't...you have the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a very advice ! I tried and have this result:
tablename: elw_e-doceo.activities - 
rows: 0.61M - 
data: 0.06G -
idx: 0.06G -
total_size: 0.11G - 
idxfrac: 0.99...
You said: "check if your table or the index actuallyfits into memory". Are you talking about my computer memory or a param of my `my.ini` ?

Comment: Have a look in your config file. It might be that `key_buffer_size` is not the right size. Please have a look at this manual entry: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size

Comment: Thanks ! I tried `key_buffer_size = 1024M` and ... (bad news) "Using temporary; Using filesort". I really don't understand :( ...